# How to view structs with truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, struct

In my contract I have a mapping like this `mapping(uint => myStruct)`

I have a `check` function where I give a `uint id` and I want to get all the info in the struct (there are strings, addresses, uints, ...) with a `call` function in my truffle `app.js`.

What's the best way to do that? Can I convert every field to a string and send an array of strings? Should I make a separate getter for each field and use as many `call` functions?

For now I just return struct and I get `invalid solidity type!: tuple`

Comment: You can't return a struct in solidity, at least for the ucrrent version. so you need to return each value on its own. something lik e: `return ( struct.member1,struct.member2)`

Comment: Please note that there is work in progress for Solidity to support serialization of complex types https://blog.ricmoo.com/solidity-abiv2-a-foray-into-the-experimental-a6afd3d47185

Comment: @MedMansour You can return each value separately in a single return? That changes everything if js can handle it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my question was misunderstood, but I solved the problem with the help of Mikko Ohtamaa in the comments.

For some reason I didn't realized I could **return multiple variables** (and of different types!) Once you know you can do this, there's no problem really. Javascript handles it very well.

My solution looks somewhat like this:

```
contract myContract {
  struct Ownable {
    string name;
    address creator;
    address currentOwner;
    bool isDestructible;
    uint price;
  }

  mapping (uint => Ownable) public Ownables;

  function getOwnableInfo(uint OwnableId) public view returns (string, address, address, bool, uint){
    Ownable o = Ownables[OwnableId];
    return (o.name, o.creator, o.currentOwner, o.isDestructible, o.price);
  }

  /.../
}
```

And in the corresponding truffle, the `call` will return an array with the variables of the return in order:

```
myContractInstance.getOwnableInfo.call(ownableId).then((resultArray => {
  name = resultArray[0];
  creator = resultArray[1];
  currentOwner = resultArray[2];
  /.../
});
```

---

Notes:

- Don't look too much into the `Ownable o = Ownables[OwnableId];`, I did that to increase readability, I don't think it's useful or a good thing at all.
- If one of the data is a big number (typically a wei price), I convert it using bignumber's `resultArray[4].toNumber()` so that JavaScript can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an extra solidity function to get the info from a struct. You can call the struct directly using web3.

It helps if you have a function on the contract to get the amount of tokens otherwise you might be stuck using while instead of for. Lets assume you have a function to give you struct.length

```
var OwnableList = [];

//to get one struct entry you do this.

function getStructData(tokenId) {

    myContract.Ownables(tokenId, function(error, details) {
        if(details == undefined) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var name = details[0];
            var creator = details[1];
            var currentOwner = details[2];
            var isDestructible = details[3];
            var price = parseInt(details[4]);
            OwnableList.push({name: name, creator: creator, currentOwner: currentOwner, isDestructible: isDestructible, price: price});
    })
    return true;
    }
}

//to get all struct entrys you do this

function dumpStructData() {
    myContract.totalOwnables(function(error, total) {
        for(i=0; i<parseInt(total); i++) {
            getStructData(i);
        }
    }
}

//now you can just read the struct

function showStruct() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(OwnableList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way for adding something into a struct and get all the records is :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract test {
    struct Record {
        string name;
        string homeAddress;
    }

    Record[] public records;

    function AddRecord(string Address , string Name) public {
        Record memory newRec = Record({
            name : Name,
            homeAddress : Address
        });

        records.push(newRec);
    }

    function recordsArrayLength() public view returns(uint256){
        return records.length;
    }

}
```

and in your ui use this code :

first use `let len = await test.methods.recordsArrayLength().call()`
and get the `length` of records array and then hit this code :

```
let records = []

for(let i=0;i<len;i++){
    records.push(await test.methods.records(i))
}
```

and now you have all the struct

Comment: So instead of returning the struct, you return an array with one struct inside?

Comment: yep that's right

Comment: I'm not sure how you understood that, but I don't want to *add* something into a struct, I just want to get all the info inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's tangential to your question, but one of the best ways to organize data is a mapped struct with an index of keys. This makes it possible to access a particular record or verify its existence without knowing which row it's on and without searching through a list. The index is an unordered list of keys that makes it possible to count the keys and enumerate the keys that exist.

```
mapping(bytes32 => RecordStruct) public recordStructs;
bytes32 public recordKeys;
```

Have a look over here for some variants, implementation details and discussion of limitations and advantages of various approaches.

[Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Also, though not shown in the examples, event emitters can make the storage state apparent to software clients. With comprehensive event logs, one can write the contract with the assumption that clients are aware of the complete state at all times. This reduces on-chain concerns considerably.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean "*without knowing which row it's on*" ? Your answer looks interesting but I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You're `mapping(uint => myStruct)` has structs stored by number and the question is about migrating to an array (also by number). I want to retrieve by key (e.g. "ORD002" or "0x123...") and I don't want to search. I also want a list and a count.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to migrate, I have a struct with several data of multiple types, and I want to write a function to `call` with truffle in order to get all that info.

Comment: I wrote an answer about how I solved my problem, maybe you'll understand better what I meant.